# For loop - check for button press - iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, events, button, for-loop

I have a simple game iOS application which will move objects on a screen by using a for loop. I also have a button which will make the objects reorder.

The only issue I have is with logic. When I press the button, the objects don't always reorder correctly. So basically, when making an app like this with a for loop, do you check for the UIButton press in the for loop or do you just put that code in the IBAction of the for loop.

I just don't get how a IBAction can correctly affect an event which is being controlled by a for loop. I hope my questions makes sense.

Or another way of thinking about my question is: Is there a way to get code which runs on press of a UIButton to work in sync with a for loop??

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: You need to replace your `for` loop with a design that properly works in an event-driven environment.

Comment: @rmaddy But I need to for loop to move the objects. Otherwise I will have to keep on calling my method thousands of times...

Comment: Without seeing code or having a better idea of what you are trying to do, it is difficult to give a good answer.

Comment: " I need to for loop". I very very very much doubt that is the case, you just think it is. Prove us wrong, post the code and we'll provide proper alternatives.

Comment: "But I need to for loop to move the objects.". That's what people who have never programmed before and/or programmed an event driven OS before say in their naivety

Comment: Oh I think I figured it out, I need to use Grand Central Dispatch to delay the loop so that it will first check if the button was pressed and then carry on with its task.

Comment: Its impossible to say, but using GCD just to check a button press seems massively inappropriate. Whats your reluctance to posting code / greater detail. Nobody can comment based on a skimpy verbal description.

Comment: Whatever you do, dont check for that kind of thing during a loop like that. If you have a collection of say 100 objects and you manage to press the button in the middle of the loop you would end up with 50 objects moved based on state 1 (before press), and 50 based on state 2 (after press). Whatever the difference between the states is.. The only solution to allow stuff to "reorder correctly" is to make sure you don't mutate the state while iterating over the collection.

Answer (score -4):

You can check outlet button with button property like selected in your action`for example
 if (button.selected)
{
for ()
  {
order
    }
[button setSelected:false];
}
else
   {
for ()
 {
reorder
 }
[button setSelected:true];
    }`